React app failing with error :react-native-screens:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'. > [CXX1210] ERROR
When I uploaded react-native-screens, I faced the below error:

error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'. > [CXX1210] C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\react_native\denemeproject\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : No compatible library found * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUİLD FAILED in 5s.


The dependencies
dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.0-alpha.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^7.0.0-alpha.20",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.31.1"
  },

Node.js v20.13.1
Npm: '10.7.0',
How to fix this error?
